# Am I using Angular 5 http interceptor correctly?

Tags: httpclient, observable, angular5, interceptor

I always return http 200 back and define my own error code. If using Promise, I could reject a response which contains customized error. How can I do it using Observable? I do it like this and it works, but is it a correct way?

My interceptor:

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
  return next.handle(req).flatMap((event: any) => {
  if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
    if (event.body.status) {
      if (event.body.status === 'NOK') {
        return Observable.throw(event.body);
      }
    }
  }
  return Observable.create(observer => observer.next(event));
})}
```

My provider:

```
private handleErrorObservable(error: Response | any) {
  return Observable.throw(error.message || error);
}

constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
}

signIn(params: any) {
  ...(some more codes here) 
  return this.http.post(this.apiUrl + func, requestData, options).map(
    (response) => {
      //do something with the response
      return response;
    }).catch(this.handleErrorObservable);
  }
```

My component:

```
if (form.valid) {
  this.auth.signIn(this.login).subscribe(val => {
    //console.log(val);
    this.navCtrl.setRoot('WebPage');
  }, err => {
  // error handling here
  })
}
```

Comment: Please let us see the constructor for 'My provider'.

Comment: @Luillyfe. Thanks for your help. I just edited the question and added the constructor